# Regex Match Whole Multiline Comment Cointaining Special Word

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to design this regex but for the life of me I could not get it to not match if */ was hit before the special word.

I'm trying to match a whole multi line comment only if it contains a special word.  I tried negative lookaheads/behinds but I could not figure out how to do it properly.

This is what I have so far:
`(?s)(/\*.+?special.+?\*/)`

Am I close or horribly off base? I tried including `(?!\*/)` unsuccessfully.

https://regex101.com/r/mD1nJ2/3

Edit: I had some redundant parts to the regex I removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not totally off base:

```
/\*                 # match /*
(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S])+? # match anything lazily, do not overrun */
special             # match special
[\s\S]+?            # match anything lazily afterwards
\*/                 # match the closing */
```

The technique is called a tempered greedy token, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mD1nJ2/4) (mind the modifiers, e.g. `x` for verbose mode !).

---

You might want to try another approach tough: analyze your document, grep the comments (using eg `BeautifulSoup`) and run string functions over them (`if "special" in comment...`).

Comment: Python `re` supports `re.DOTALL` modifier, no need using `[\s\S]` workaround as a mere dot will do. Look, OP is already using the inline version of the dotall flag `(?s)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I guess more of a habit - `DOTALL` would be equally well, I reckon.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you!

Comment: Well, not at all really. Jan's tempered greedy token solution was working even without my remark that's why I  upvoted it.